# Data type confusion... for word with both alphabet and numbers eg. tlc5?

Tags: vba, excel

In my code i want to provide inputs which are both alphabet and numbers. Eg- tlc5. What data type should i use for such an input since only integer or only string isn't working?

Comment: You should be using string. What do you mean "string isn't working"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having seen your current code: use string. VBA can convert any number to a string.

e.g.

```
Dim i as Integer
Dim s as String

i = 2
s = "test" & i
```

will result in a string "test2". To convert any other data type to a string there is the CStr() function.

If you need to work with a number contained in said string later on, I would suggest you store the number and string in a seperate variables as show above.

Comment: That was an example of how to deal with different data types when you need a number in a string and for example in a calculation.

Comment: I used variant instead and it worked with that. I did not have to concatenate string and integer variables. Thanx for the help anyways guys.